# Jenkins build failed: package org.eclipse.swt does not exist

Tags: java, jenkins, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to build a RCP product in Jenkins with configuration: maven: 3.0.5 and Java 1.7. It is building locally but failing with the following error in Jenkins.

```
 Started calculate disk usage of build
 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
 [INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
 [INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
 [INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
 [INFO] Total time: 7.360 s
 [INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-24T13:55:12-05:00
 [INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
 Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myrcp-app: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[8,23] package org.eclipse.swt does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[9,30] package org.eclipse.swt.events does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[10,30] package org.eclipse.swt.events does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[11,32] package org.eclipse.swt.graphics does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[12,30] package org.eclipse.swt.layout does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[13,30] package org.eclipse.swt.layout does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[14,30] package org.eclipse.swt.layout does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[15,31] package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[16,31] package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[17,31] package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[18,31] package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[19,31] package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[20,31] package org.eclipse.swt.widgets does not exist
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/internal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[45,39] cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol:   class Dialog
 [ERROR] location: class com.company.myrcp.app.internal.handlers.AboutHandler
 [ERROR] /c:/jenkins/workspace/myrcp-app/src/main/java/com/company/myrcp/app/nternal/handlers/AboutHandler.java:[47,34] cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol:   class Shell
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR]
```

The following dependency is also present in POM:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt</artifactId>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Not sure if I have to add any plugins to make it run in Jenkins?

Comment: Is there a reason you did not specify a version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven you specify the version. Once you successfully built-in local version you can investigate is all the dependency is available. If you try to run in eclipse internally eclipse understand the dependency and help your build in local.

Fortunately, if you are running Jenkins in another machine to build the code from repo you have to specify the version and maven downloads the dependency and get it build.

It can be eliminated by maintaining the remote repository internally. If you have an internal repo then consider checking the repo availability.